How to find the minimal amount of steps to visit all of the graph, when all visited nodes can also visit other nodes
The problem can be easier to understand if you imagine it like a disease spreading, where all the infected can spread the disease to one other target. Consider the patient-zero as the starting node. It spreads to only ONE other node on the first step, and on the second turn both of the "infected" nodes can spread to two or less others, depending on the connections of the whole graph.
I've been struggling to write the algorithm on my own and could not find anything useful online because it is hard to write the problem in general terms.
My current code travels based on the degree of the node. The current infected node spreads it to the node, that is connected and has the largest number of connections. The spreading order is also modified, so that all the nodes with less connections can be used first to increase the chance that more nodes are "infected".
Also tried to count the neighbors of each sub-graph, but that method failed in test 1.
Any link to a algorithm i should check out would be appreciated.
My current code in python:
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt



class Node:
    def __init__(self, value, neighbors):
        self.value = value #the number of the node
        self.neighbors = neighbors #connections to other nodes
        self.power = len(neighbors) #number of connections
        self.visited = None #array of visited nodes



class Graph:
    def __init__(self, nodes):
        self.nodes = nodes
        for i in range(len(self.nodes)):

            #Creating the array of nodes that can be visited (marked by 0)
            #And those whose can't be visited (marked by -1)
            nodes[i].visited = [-1 for j in range(len(self.nodes))]
            for m in range(len(self.nodes[i].neighbors)):
                self.nodes[i].visited[nodes[i].neighbors[m]-1] = 0
        
        #Array used to check if every node is visited. Should be all 1's if all are visited
        self.globalVisits = [0 for i in range(len(nodes))]
    #Returns node if indexed by the value
    def getNode(self,index):
        return self.nodes[index-1]
    
    def allVisited(self):
        return not 0 in self.globalVisits

#Helper function to paint the spreading process and initiate the main algorithm
def findValue(graph, start,drawing, pos):
    graph.globalVisits[start-1]=1 #Marking the staring position
    visited = [start] #Initializing array of visited nodes
    order = [[start]] #Initializing array of order of visits
    result = spreadRumour(graph, visited, order) #Finding the steps to spread through all of the graph

#Painting the graph
    for cell in order:
        for number in cell:
            drawing.nodes[number]['color'] = 'green'
        plt.clf()
        node_colors = [drawing.nodes[node].get('color', 'red') for node in drawing.nodes]
        nx.draw(drawing,pos, with_labels=True, font_weight='bold', node_color=node_colors)
        plt.pause(0.5)
        plt.ioff()
        plt.show()

    print(f"Spread order: {order}") #Printing order
    return result

def spreadRumour(graph, visited,order):
    travels = 0
    while not graph.allVisited():
        change = False

        travels += 1
        lastOrder = order[len(order) - 1].copy()
        for i in range(len(visited)):

            maxP = -1 #Max power
            nextNode = None #node.Value of the next node
            current = graph.getNode(visited[i]) #Current node that is spreading

            for j in range(len(current.visited)):
                #Checking if the node can spread locally and globally 
                if current.visited[j] ==0 and graph.globalVisits[j] == 0:
                    #Checking if the power is greatest of all neighbors
                    if graph.getNode(j+1).power>maxP:
                        #Marking power and the spreading target
                        maxP = graph.getNode(j+1).power
                        nextNode = j+1
            if nextNode != None:
                #Mark that the spread is still happening
                change = True

                #Mark visited nodes in graph context
                graph.globalVisits[nextNode-1]=1
                graph.globalVisits[current.value-1]=1

                #Decrease the power and mark visits in the next node
                graph.getNode(nextNode).visited[visited[i]-1]=1
                graph.getNode(nextNode).power -= 1

                #Decrease the power and mark visits in the current node
                current.visited[nextNode-1]=1
                current.power -=1

                #Update visited nodes list and update the spread order
                visited.append(nextNode)
                lastOrder.append(nextNode)
            
            #Marking the order
            if(order[len(order) - 1] != lastOrder):
                order.append(lastOrder)
        #Checking if the algorithm still makes progress 
        if change == False:
            print("Failed to spread to all")
            break
        #Sorting nodes by the number of connections
        visited.sort(key=lambda x: graph.getNode(x).power)
        # print(visited)
    return travels
# test 1
#vertices = [[1, [2,3]], [2, [1,3]], [3, [1,4,5]], [4, [3]], [5, [3]]]

# test 2
# vertices = [
#     [1, [2, 3, 4, 5, 6]],
#     [2, [1]],
#     [3, [1]],
#     [4, [1]],
#     [5, [1, 7, 8, 9, 10, 15, 17]],
#     [6, [1, 11, 12, 13, 14, 16, 18]],
#     [7, [5, 8, 9, 10]],
#     [8, [5, 7, 9, 10]],
#     [9, [5, 7, 8, 10]],
#     [10, [5, 7, 8, 9]],
#     [11, [6, 12, 13, 14]],
#     [12, [6, 11, 13, 14]],
#     [13, [6, 11, 12, 14]],
#     [14, [6, 11, 12, 13]],
#     [15, [5]],
#     [16, [6]],
#     [17, [5]],
#     [18, [6]]
# ]

# test 3
vertices = [
    [1, [2, 3, 5, 8, 12]],
    [2, [1, 3, 4]],
    [3, [1, 2, 4]],
    [4, [2, 3]],
    [5, [1, 6, 7]],
    [6, [5, 7]],
    [7, [5, 6]],
    [8, [1, 9, 10]],
    [9, [8, 10, 11]],
    [10, [8, 9]],
    [11, [9]],
    [12, [1, 13]],
    [13, [12, 14, 15]],
    [14, [13, 15]],
    [15, [13, 14]]
]

#creating nodes and the graph objects
nodes = [Node(x[0], x[1]) for x in vertices]
graph = Graph(nodes)

#drawing the initial graph
G = nx.Graph()
for i in range(len(graph.nodes)):
    for j in range(len(graph.getNode(i+1).neighbors)):
        G.add_edge(graph.getNode(i+1).value, graph.getNode(i+1).neighbors[j])
pos = nx.spring_layout(G)

nx.draw(G,pos, with_labels=True, font_weight="bold", node_color="red")
plt.show()

#printing result
print(f"Was spread through the graph in {findValue(graph,1,G, pos)} turns")

The test that is not commented can be cleared in 5 turns, however my program clears it in 7.

Looks like python.  Why not so tagged?

This is a graph theory problem.  Please use graph terminology.  "the number of connections (power) of the node."  This is called the degree of the node.

"on the second turn both of the "infected" nodes can spread to two or less others, "  Does this mean two others all together, or does it mean that each node can spread to two others ( that is 4 all together )?

Two all together, at most. I meant that for n nodes, they can spread to n or less nodes, because a node might no longer be connected to any "non-infected" nodes.

OK.  Please edit your question to clarify this.  You still have not tagged your question with your code tag.

To find the minimum steps to visit all nodes, you need to find the maximum depth of the tree rooted at your started node.  That can be done using a depth first search ( DFS ).  You can find lots of code to implement a DFS.

Do you suggest running the DFS algorithm for all the nodes, who are already "infected"? A stand-alone DFS does not take into account that every more visited nodes can travel.

The DFS starts at the patient-zero node, and runs once.  "DFS does not take into account ..." certainly it does.  You should probably read an article on how DFS works.
